# show that a perfectly normal space is completely normal

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

The problem I want to ask is in the post title. It's in Munkres books. I type it one more time below for you

> > Show that a perfectly normal space is completely normal.

In perfectly normal space, every closed set is a $G_{\delta}$ set. Let $A$, $B$ be separated sets in $X$. Because $\bar{A}, \bar{B}$ are closed $G_{\delta}$ in normal space $X$, so we can find 2 continuous functions $f, g$ vanish precisely on $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{B}$ respectively. This is where I got stuck. Let $h = f - g$, then $h$ is continous. I need to find 2 disjoint open sets $C,D$ in $[-1,1]$ such that $h^{-1}(C)$ contains $A$ and $h^{-1}(D)$ contains $B$. But I can't find them.

Thanks everybody. I really I appreciate if some one can help me solve this.

Comment: I previously answered this question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/249354/8348).

Comment: @ArthurFischer I read your answer, but can you please try proving this problem in my way. It's the hint in the book, and I think it can lead to a simpler solution. Thanks...

Comment: There its a slight error in your write up: you want $f,g$ to vanish on the _closures_ of $A,B$, respectively, not the sets themselves.

Comment: Yes, right. I've already edited it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(After taking note of my comment to the question above)

**Hint:** Since $A$ and $B$ are separated, then $h(x) < 0$ for each $x \in A$ and $h(x) > 0$ for each $x \in B$.

Answer (score 4):

1. In a perfecly normal space $X$ all closed sets are $G_\delta$ and so all open sets are $F_\sigma$.
2. A space $X$ is completely normal iff all open subspaces are normal.
3. An $F_\sigma$ subspace of a normal space is normal.

For a proof of 3. see my note [here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/07.pdf) or any decent textbook.

Together these imply what you want.